# there WOULD be at least 10 people and out of that 10 people at least 2 WOULD

Tags: grammaticality, descriptive-grammar, would

Context- I was teaching a child about how the economy is being effected by the corona-virus. I pointed at a street with some stores and restaurants and said:

"If it weren't for the virus there **would** be at least 10 people out there and out of that 10 people at least 2 **would** buy something."

I've never used this kind of structure before where there are two 'woulds' one after another. Did I use it correctly?
And is there any better way of saying it?

Comment: There are other ways to express it, but it sounds reasonably valid to me.  (Might benefit from some punctuation, though.)

Comment: I would slightly rephrase as "out of **those** 10 people..."

Comment: I would rephrase it as "and of those ten at least two would buy something."You don't need to repeat 'people'.